# Laravel Eloquent Relationship Filter by Column of Relationship

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

I have 3 Tables

> Product:[Table]
>
> Person:[Table]
>
> Payment:[Table]

Many To Many Relationship Between Product and Person

One To Many Relationship Between Product and Payment (One  Product Has Many Payments)

One To Many Relationship Between Person and Payment (One Person Has Many Payments)

```
Payment:[Table]
    id
    person_id
    product_id
    amount
```

The thing is that i am trying to get All persons with products and Product payments filtered by `person_id`.

Reason is that i dont want to have any other persons record in payments.

This is actually the query i am running yeah i know its wrong cuz i cant filter it by `person_id`.

```
$query = $person::with('product', 'payment')->where('is_active', 1);
```

I want to achieve something like this..

```
 $query = $person::with(array('product', 'payment' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('person_id', '=', 'person.id');
}))->where('is_active', 1);
```

Comment: I'm not confident here, but give a try to your second example, but replace `payment` with `product.payment`.

Comment: Empty Array of payment,  query is wrong ;(

Comment: If you are querying the `persons` table and eagerly loading `payments` and `products`, and you want to filter by a specific person, then you simply filter the `persons` table.  E.g. $query = $person::with('product', 'payment')->where('is_active', 1)->where('id', ID_TO_FIND).  Laravel first gets all persons with persons.id = ID_TO_FIND, then it loads any payments and products for that person.

Comment: well thats not solution. i am trying to get list of persons so i dont want to get only one record of person. Thing is that if i get record with Person->Payment relationship it gets payment list right but i want to get product->Payments filtered by person_id, as it takes some different person records there ))

Comment: [link](https://gist.github.com/mjaniko/63107db1e4ae9f04c297ec3514eaa2c1)  This is the result

Answer (score 0):

If you setup your relations like:

```
class Person extends Model
{
    public function payments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Payment::class);
    }
}

class Payment extends Model
{
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
$person = Person::with('payments.product')->where('id',$personId)->where('is_active',1)->first();
```

Which will return a `Person` with all the relations loaded and you can access those like:

```
@foreach($person->payments as $payment)
    {{$person->name}} bought {{$payment->product->name}} for {{$payment->amount}}
@endforeach
```